# Service reference ignores some parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, service-reference

I'm new in web services.
I have a SOAP web service which contains many different methods and I need to create a client application to this service using C#. I added a service reference in VS 2015 and I even can send request to this service and get response. `Reference.cs` file contains needed proxy-classes, etc. But when I try to execute some methods, some parameters of this method are just ignores in XML, which is send to service. For example, the method `mergeLocationTypes`:

```
MyTestReference.WsEndpointServiceFacadePortTypeClient client = new MyTestReference.WsEndpointServiceFacadePortTypeClient("WsEndpointServiceFacadeHttpSoap11Endpoint");
MyTestReference.WsLocationTypeDTO[] Args = new MyTestReference.WsLocationTypeDTO[1];
Args[0] = new MyTestReference.WsLocationTypeDTO();
Args[0].id = "Test_id";
Args[0].kind = "Test_kind";
Args[0].order = 3;
client.mergeLocationTypes(Args);
```

I use the Fiddler to look at the content of the XML and I see that XML doesn't have an order tag, but have id and kind.
Code of `WsLocationTypeDTO`:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://AddressToNamespace/xsd")]
public partial class WsLocationTypeDTO : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string idField;

    private string kindField;

    private System.Nullable<int> orderField;

    private bool orderFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public string kind {
        get {
            return this.kindField;
        }
        set {
            this.kindField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("kind");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=2)]
    public System.Nullable<int> order {
        get {
            return this.orderField;
        }
        set {
            this.orderField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("order");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool orderSpecified {
        get {
            return this.orderFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.orderFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("orderSpecified");
        }
    }
```

Another method with this problem has many parameters and only two (lat and lng) are ignores in result XML. This method is `mergeLocations(WsLocationDTO[] Args)`. Code of `WsLocationDTO`:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://AddressToNamespace/xsd")]
public partial class WsLocationDTO : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string addressField;

    private WsLocationAttributeDTO[] attributesField;

    private string cityField;

    private string idField;

    private System.Nullable<double> latField;

    private bool latFieldSpecified;

    private System.Nullable<double> lngField;

    private bool lngFieldSpecified;

    private string logicalIdField;

    private string nameField;

    private string operationTimeField;

    private WsLocationServiceDTO[] servicesField;

    private WsLocationStatusDTO[] statusesField;

    private WsLocationTypeDTO typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string address {
        get {
            return this.addressField;
        }
        set {
            this.addressField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("address");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attributes", IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public WsLocationAttributeDTO[] attributes {
        get {
            return this.attributesField;
        }
        set {
            this.attributesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("attributes");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=2)]
    public string city {
        get {
            return this.cityField;
        }
        set {
            this.cityField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("city");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=3)]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=4)]
    public System.Nullable<double> lat {
        get {
            return this.latField;
        }
        set {
            this.latField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("lat");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool latSpecified {
        get {
            return this.latFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.latFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("latSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=5)]
    public System.Nullable<double> lng {
        get {
            return this.lngField;
        }
        set {
            this.lngField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("lng");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool lngSpecified {
        get {
            return this.lngFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.lngFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("lngSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=6)]
    public string logicalId {
        get {
            return this.logicalIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.logicalIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("logicalId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=7)]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=8)]
    public string operationTime {
        get {
            return this.operationTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.operationTimeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("operationTime");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("services", IsNullable=true, Order=9)]
    public WsLocationServiceDTO[] services {
        get {
            return this.servicesField;
        }
        set {
            this.servicesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("services");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("statuses", IsNullable=true, Order=10)]
    public WsLocationStatusDTO[] statuses {
        get {
            return this.statusesField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("statuses");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=11)]
    public WsLocationTypeDTO type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("type");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this happens. What a reason of this (web service or my auto-generated proxy-class or another.)? 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.